# Can this reflective Java routine be sped up?

Tags: java, reflection, benchmarking

I've tried to find some kind of definitive answer on reflection performance characteristics.  Outside of the "don't use it unless you have to", there's nothing really concrete.  Maybe that's okay because the use case dictates how well or poorly the reflection routine runs.

I'd let it go but I've read several articles that suggest that Java 6 makes reflection routines nearly as fast as any other routine, especially if you use the -server switch.

I'm not seeing that at all.  I'm using Java 6 on Mac 10.8.4.

Behold my routine.  I only use Random stuff so that hopefully the compiler/runtime isn't optimizing on literals in some way.  I've left my for loop running for a long time and I'm always getting values of about 13-15 ms for the direct routine and about 590-595ms for the reflective routine.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Random;


public class Reflection {

    static final int ITERATIONS = 100000;

    static final String[] STRINGS = { "asdf", "qwer", "dfgh", "scvb", "ertyerty" };

    static final Random random = new Random( System.currentTimeMillis() );

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        for ( int i = 0; true; i++ ) {
            System.out.println( "i=" + i + ", direct=" + testDirectCallSpeed() + ", reflective=" + testReflectiveCallSpeed() );
        }
    }

    static class Blah {
        String a, b, c, d, e, f;
        int g, h, i, j, k, l;
        public String toString() { 
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( 100 );
            sb.append( super.toString() );
            sb.append( ", a=" ).append( a );
            sb.append( ", b=" ).append( b );
            sb.append( ", c=" ).append( c );
            sb.append( ", d=" ).append( d );
            sb.append( ", e=" ).append( e );
            sb.append( ", f=" ).append( f );
            sb.append( ", g=" ).append( g );
            sb.append( ", h=" ).append( h );
            sb.append( ", i=" ).append( i );
            sb.append( ", j=" ).append( j );
            sb.append( ", k=" ).append( k );
            sb.append( ", l=" ).append( l );
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }

    public static long testDirectCallSpeed() {
        System.gc();
        Blah[] blahs = new Blah[ ITERATIONS ];
        long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Blah blah;
        for ( int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++ ) {
            blah = new Blah();
            blah.a = getString();
            blah.b = getString();
            blah.c = getString();
            blah.d = getString();
            blah.e = getString();
            blah.f = getString();
            blah.g = getInt();
            blah.h = getInt();
            blah.i = getInt();
            blah.j = getInt();
            blah.k = getInt();
            blah.l = getInt();
            blahs[ i ] = blah;
        }
        printRandomBlah( blahs );
        return System.currentTimeMillis() - begin;
    }

    public static long testReflectiveCallSpeed() throws Exception {
        System.gc();
        Blah[] blahs = new Blah[ ITERATIONS ];
        long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Blah blah;
        Class<?> type;
        for ( int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++ ) {
            blah = new Blah();
            for ( Field f : Blah.class.getDeclaredFields() ) {
                type = f.getType();
                if ( String.class == type ) f.set( blah, getString() );
                else if ( int.class == type ) f.setInt( blah, getInt() );
            }
            blahs[ i ] = blah;
        }
        printRandomBlah( blahs );
        return System.currentTimeMillis() - begin;
    }

    public static void printRandomBlah( Blah[] blahs ) {
//      System.out.println( blahs[ random.nextInt( blahs.length ) ] );
    }

    public static int getInt() { return random.nextInt(); }
    public static String getString() { return STRINGS[ random.nextInt( STRINGS.length ) ]; }

}
```

Comment: I think Java takes some time to find the Fields, Methods, Classes, but then caches them so the second access should be just as fast. Try to run the reflective part a second time.

Comment: So... you came to the conclusion that the jvm is not optimizing well when you specifically try to prevent it from doing that?

Comment: My guess is that fast-path optimization relies on the reflected `Field` being the same each time; this lets the compiler rip out the reflection and replace it with normal access (after a quick check to verify that the field is indeed the same). In your case, `Field f` is different each iteration -- let alone each method -- and thus the compiler can't optimize it.

Comment: @yshavit's comment is correct.  Do the reflection once and hang on to the Field objects.  It'll still be slower then regular access, but including all the metata lookups in your loop is what's killing it.

Comment: @kiheru, I admit this example is terribly contrived.  I'm trying to write a small library that uses annotations to perform operations on a database.  This is mostly to better learn how all of that works.  I didn't think anyone would care about that when the question is about how to make reflection faster.  In my experiment, I want to loop through all of the database fields, call field.get on them so I can populate my PreparedStatement.  Thus, the looping on the declared fields.

Comment: Thank you @yshavit and lscoughlin.  I suspected it was the loop, but I didn't know what to do instead.  Hanging on to Field objects is slick.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis In my question I mention that I'm letting the loop run for a long time.  I have rerun the program several times and it's consistent.

Comment: @bmauter later invocations on the same field objects go faster.  It can't jit it back to something close to an astore if you keep reinitializing the reference ( doing the metadata lookup in the loop. ) so SotiriosDelimanolis is correct, but it doesn't apply to your original function.  For the app as you've mini-described it, Your overhead on the prepared statements and io time is going to be an exponent of your reflection time, especially if you cache sane descriptor constructs to do the actual reflection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you extract all of the time in your "testReflectiveCall" stuff that is not actually calling the setter, it's almost an immeasurable difference.  The time spent is spent in your list navigation array iteration, and metadata lookups, not really in the reflective call.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Random;
public class Reflection {

    static final int ITERATIONS = 100;

    static final String[] STRINGS = { "asdf", "qwer", "dfgh", "scvb", "ertyerty" };

    static final Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    static Field fielda;
    static Field fieldb;
    static Field fieldc;
    static Field fieldd;
    static Field fielde;
    static Field fieldf;
    static Field fieldg;
    static Field fieldh;
    static Field fieldi;
    static Field fieldj;
    static Field fieldk;
    static Field fieldl;

    static {
        try {
            fielda = Blah.class.getField("a");
            fieldb = Blah.class.getField("b");
            fieldc = Blah.class.getField("c");
            fieldd = Blah.class.getField("d");
            fielde = Blah.class.getField("e");
            fieldf = Blah.class.getField("f");
            fieldg = Blah.class.getField("g");
            fieldh = Blah.class.getField("h");
            fieldi = Blah.class.getField("i");
            fieldj = Blah.class.getField("j");
            fieldk = Blah.class.getField("k");
            fieldl = Blah.class.getField("l");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        for (int i = 0; true; i++) {
            System.out.println("i=" + i + ", direct=" + testDirectCallSpeed() + ", reflective=" + testReflectiveCallSpeed());
        }
    }

    static class Blah {

        public String a, b, c, d, e, f;
        public int g, h, i, j, k, l;

        public String toString() {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(100);
            sb.append(super.toString());
            sb.append(", a=").append(a);
            sb.append(", b=").append(b);
            sb.append(", c=").append(c);
            sb.append(", d=").append(d);
            sb.append(", e=").append(e);
            sb.append(", f=").append(f);
            sb.append(", g=").append(g);
            sb.append(", h=").append(h);
            sb.append(", i=").append(i);
            sb.append(", j=").append(j);
            sb.append(", k=").append(k);
            sb.append(", l=").append(l);
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }

    public static long testDirectCallSpeed() {

        System.gc();
        Blah[] blahs = new Blah[ITERATIONS];
        long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Blah blah;
        for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
            blah = new Blah();
            blah.a = getString();
            blah.b = getString();
            blah.c = getString();
            blah.d = getString();
            blah.e = getString();
            blah.f = getString();
            blah.g = getInt();
            blah.h = getInt();
            blah.i = getInt();
            blah.j = getInt();
            blah.k = getInt();
            blah.l = getInt();
            blahs[i] = blah;
        }
        long exectionTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - begin;
        printRandomBlah(blahs);
        return exectionTime;
    }

    public static long testReflectiveCallSpeed() throws Exception {

        System.gc();
        Blah[] blahs = new Blah[ITERATIONS];
        long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Blah blah;
        for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
            blah = new Blah();
            fielda.set(blah, getString());
            fieldb.set(blah, getString());
            fieldc.set(blah, getString());
            fieldd.set(blah, getString());
            fielde.set(blah, getString());
            fieldf.set(blah, getString());
            fieldg.set(blah, getInt());
            fieldh.set(blah, getInt());
            fieldi.set(blah, getInt());
            fieldj.set(blah, getInt());
            fieldk.set(blah, getInt());
            fieldl.set(blah, getInt());
            blahs[i] = blah;
        }
        long executionTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - begin;
        printRandomBlah(blahs);
        return executionTime;

    }

    public static void printRandomBlah(Blah[] blahs) {

        // System.out.println(blahs[random.nextInt(blahs.length)]);
    }

    public static int getInt() {

        return random.nextInt();
    }

    public static String getString() {

        return STRINGS[random.nextInt(STRINGS.length)];
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you!  So, if I still needed to access these fields via a name, I could instead loop in the static init block and put the Field objects in a Map?  Is that reasonable or could that cause the class to never garbage collect?

Comment: @bmauter You'd also probably lose the speed advantage of the faster calls in the hash table lookup.

Comment: @kiheru Your "probably" is more like "definitely".  :)  I wrote a third test called testCachedReflectiveCallSpeed.  I'm getting approximately 13-15ms for direct, 600ms for reflective and 442ms for cached.

Comment: anything you do that's not directly calling astore is going to be slower then just calling astore.  Seriously, hit this up with pcode and you'll see what I mean.  Do you care about every last ounce of performance, or do you care about how general the code can be?  we can tell you how to many anything as fast or as flexible as it can be, but we can't make the design decisions for you.

Comment: Thank you.  I understand the tradeoff of flexibility and performance.  I was just looking for any wisdom about how to cheat that tradeoff.  You guys have already helped me do 25% (442ms vs 600ms) better, so I think this question was worth it.